# Small caps bold

Tags: fonts, fontspec, bold, small-caps

I downloaded and installed [this](https://freefontsfamily.com/bembo-std-font-free/) font on my pc. In particular, I should have the normal, bold and semibold-italic versions.
On latex, I tried to insert some text as small caps bold in this font, but it won't work. Small caps alone does work though.
This is how I wrote it:

```
{\fontspec{Bembo Std}\fontsize{16}{12}{\textsc{\textbf My Text}}}
```

So, I have some questions:

1. Is it possible that the font is available bold and small caps but not both together?
2. Are there any similar fonts you are aware that could do the job?
3. Is there a way to force this, "faking" the bold or the small caps?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: that's not clearly a licenced download but anyway fontspec may not be able to guess the font names of all variants you can supply them in the optional argumet to `\newfontfamily` (or `\fontspec` but it usually makes sense to declare the fonts in advance not use `\fontspec` mid document.

Comment: `\fontsize{16}{12}` means 16pt font on baselines 12pt apart, did you mean that? it is usually better to use standard sizes such as `\Large`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle although I would not be happy to pay, I have not really found where to download a licensed version. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. I am actually trying to recreate the page of a word file which has some text with dimension 16, and since it has to be as similar as possible I thought it would be better giving the exact value.

Comment: but why 12pt baselines?  (and if you want the exact value you probably want 16bp not 16 which is 16pt which is smaller than Word's 16pt by a factor of 72/72.27

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Honestly, I do not know what baselines are. I took that part from online, I searched how to change font size. Your suggestion on the 16bp has been ver interesting and useful though. Thank you a lot.

Comment: the vertical space between one line of text and the line below it, you are specifying letters that are 16pt high to be written on to lines that are 12pt apart, tex can not achieve that as it's not achievable so it will just pack the letters as close together as possible giving uneven lines you almos always want the second argument of `\fontsize` to be 20% more than the first argument, eg the default 10pt text on 12pt baseline

Comment: I have not checked, but it's entirely possible (probable, even) that your font is simply lacking bold small-cap glyphs. I know quite a few of mine do.